# Move entity objects from one entitycollection to another

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is it possible to move relationships from on entity to another?

I have table *Users* which has a *1..**-relation to a table called *Cars*. In one part of my code I want user to superseed another one, i.e. move all of the Cars relationships to the new user. In SQL it could be achieved like this, but whatabout entity framework?

```
UPDATE Cars SET UserId = @newUserId WHERE UserId = @oldUserId
```

I'd like the solution to be as generic as possible so that I can reuse it when needed. How would you go about to achieve this?

Below you find some of what I've tried so far.

**By just copying**

```
newUser.Cars = oldUser.Cars;
oldUser.Cars = new EntityCollection<Cars>();
```

**By delete and insert**

```
public static void MoveFrom<T>(this EntityCollection<T> to,
                               EntityCollection<T> from)
                               where T : class, IEntityWithRelationships
{
  foreach (T item in from.ToArray())
  {
    from.Remove(item);
    to.Add(item);
  }
}
```

**Using CopyTo**

```
public static void MoveFrom<T>(this EntityCollection<T> to,
                               EntityCollection<T> from)
                               where T : class, IEntityWithRelationships
{
  T[] array = new T[from.Count()];
  from.CopyTo(array, 0);

  foreach (T item in array)
  {
    to.Add(item);
  }
}
```

This last one is recommended in [Copying from EntityCollection to EntityCollection impossible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663414) but gives me the following error

> A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: A primary key
>   property that is a part of referential integrity constraint cannot be
>   changed when the dependent object is Unchanged unless it is being set
>   to the association's principal object. The principal object must be
>   tracked and not marked for deletion.