# Adding several items to an EntityCollection using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to set an `EntityCollection` property (`v.TPM_USER2`) to a subset of users in my database.  I have the array `view.DNs` which contains a list of usernames to add.  I can do this with:

```
if(view.DNs != null && view.DNs.Length > 0)
{
   var users = (from u in context.TPM_USER where view.DNs.Contains(u.DN) select u);
   foreach (var u in users)
   {
      v.TPM_USER2.Add(u);
   }
}
```

This works fine, however I have a feeling there's a way to do this with a single line of code.  I've tried:

```
v.TPM_USER2 = (from u in context.TPM_USER where view.DNs.Contains(u.DN) select u);
```

Which results in the error:

> Error 78  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable' to
>   'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection

I've tried using `ToArray()` as well without any luck.  Is there a way to do this?

**UPDATE:**

I also tried:

```
v.TPM_USER2.Attach(from u in context.TPM_USER where view.DNs.Contains(u.DN) select u);
```

Which compiles, but generates the runtime error:

> Attach is not a valid operation when the source object associated with
>   this related end is in an added, deleted, or detached state. Objects
>   loaded using the NoTracking merge option are always detached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v.TPM_User2.AddRange(users);`

**Edit**: That was for `EntitySet` - looks like you may be stuck with foreach. Alternatively, you could write your own `AddRange` extension method to do the looping for you if you're dedicated to doing it one line.

Comment: `EntityCollection` doesn't appear to have a method called `AddRange`, is it an extension method?

Comment: Oh, I was thinking of `EntitySet<T>`. Try CopyTo()? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663414/copying-from-entitycollection-to-entitycollection-impossible

Comment: Ugh, that may not work either - you may just have to stick with the foreach

Comment: The `CopyTo` method of `EntityCollection` copies *to* an array, I guess I would need something like `CopyFrom` - Hmmm.

Comment: Yeah - looks like you may be stuck `foreach`ing it or writing an `AddRange` extension method.

Comment: Ok, I figured maybe there was an easy solution but perhaps what I have here is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: I'd say that's totally reasonable.